# Adjoining greatest and smallest elements to uncountable ordered field

Tags: order-theory, ordered-fields

As titled. With $\mathbb{R}$, we can adjoin $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ as the greatest and smallest elements and define $\overline{\mathbb{R}}:=[-\infty, +\infty]$. But if we have an ordered field $\mathbb{F}$ with a cardinal number larger or equal to $2^{\aleph_1}$, can we still do similar things and define $\overline{\mathbb{F}}$? I only know of well-orderings and the definition of ordinal numbers. But $\mathbb{F}$ is not well-ordered. Hence the question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well-orderings have nothing to do with it. $\mathbb R$ is not well-ordered. It *can* be well-ordered (assuming the axiom of choice) but those well-orderings have nothing to do with the structure of $\mathbb R$ as an ordered field. And I don't see what is to stop you from extending any ordered field with $\pm\infty$.

Comment: By the way it could be that $\mathbb R$ itself is an ordered field of cardinal number $2^{\aleph_1}$, that is, it's possible that $2^{\aleph_1}=2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: @user14111 Thanks! I'm not familiar with these things, so I'm just trying to be extra cautious. If anything is even slightly different to a known object, I just assume I can't apply any old conclusions on the new.